# React Native Error: Attempting to run JS driven animation on animated node that has been moved to "native" earlier by starting an animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-textinput

I am using version `0.61.4` of React Naive and I found it a strange problem.

When focusing on TextInput(with default props) I get the following error:

> Attempting to run JS driven animation on animated node that has been moved to "native" earlier by starting an animation with `useNativeDriver: true`

Note: This problem occurs when the Input is at the bottom half of the page.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem on android react version 0.62.2 with
BottomNavigation from react-native-material-bottom-navigation package

then I:

- head to the node modules
- targeted react-native-material-bottom-navigation folder
- searched in all JS files for where useNativeDriver is used
- added this line before it :useNativeDriver: true

as this comment recommended, worked perfectly fine
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61117885/10431723