# Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified issue of ReactNativeBase Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I created a new react-native project today (April 3rd, 2020) and added a native-base. Then I tried to add input with the floating label. It gives a warning message: `Animated: useNativeDriver was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to true or false`. If I removed the floating label attribute or changed it to stackedLabel the warning disappeared. While this warning is appearing, `onChangeText` is not being called.

[image: Warning message]

**Component File**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {Input, Item, Label} from 'native-base';

import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

declare var global: {HermesInternal: null | {}};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label>Test</Label>
              <Input onChangeText={text => console.log(text)} />
            </Item>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "formtest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.25.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Just add `useNativeDriver: true` to the animation config.

```
const [animatePress, setAnimatePress] = useState(new Animated.Value(1))

const animateIn = () => {
  Animated.timing(animatePress, {
    toValue: 0.5,
    duration: 500,
    useNativeDriver: true // Add This line
  }).start();
}
```

## UPDATED

**Solution:**

As the warning says, we need to specify the  `useNativeDriver` option explicitly and set it to  `true`  or  `false` .

**1- Animation methods**

Refer to  [Animated doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated) , with animation types or composition functions, for example, `Animated.decay()`, `Animated.timing()`,
`Animated.spring()`, `Animated.parallel()`, `Animated.sequence()`, specify  `useNativeDriver` .

```
Animated.timing(this.state.animatedValue, {
  toValue: 1,
  duration: 500,
  useNativeDriver: true, // Add this line
}).start();
```

**2- Animatable components**

`Animated` exports the following animatable components using the above wrapper:

- `Animated.Image`
- `Animated.ScrollView`
- `Animated.Text`
- `Animated.View`
- `Animated.FlatList`
- `Animated.SectionList`

When working with `Animated.event()` , add `useNativeDriver: false/true` to the animation config.

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  scrollEventThrottle={1}
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.animatedValue } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true } // Add this line
  )}
>
  {content}
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, may i know where to find and edit the Animated.timing?

Comment: you can not simply add another answer in your answer without specifying his/her name

Comment: @Nisharg Shah - That's your right, but I read that in github.com : 
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3109#issuecomment-698318985
I removed it from my answer, as I told I read that in Github

Comment: No issues but you must specify the name if you update your answer after some person add the same answer in your post, that's why I told you and these the regular behavior of SO

Comment: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3109#issuecomment-698318985

Answer (score 32):

Facing the same issue for a long time and still no update from native-base developers yet in 2021.

Meanwhile use a workaround to avoid irritating yellow warnings of `useNativeDriver`.

#### UPDATE RN V0.63 ABOVE

`YellowBox` is now changed and replace with `LogBox`

**FUNCTIONAL**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
}, [])
```

**CLASS BASED**

```
import React from 'react';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
}
```

#### UPDATE RN V0.63 BELOW

**FUNCTIONAL**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
}, [])
```

**CLASS BASED**

```
import React from 'react';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
}
```

Comment: That helped me out

Comment: what does functional mean? where should I add this? would that work for all the apperances of the message?

Comment: React is written in two styles, Functional based and class based, you must to add that code in those, where you want to ignore those warning

Comment: Idk I'm just saying it's a warning and hiding the warning is not the same as fixing the warning yeah? But I am also going to hide the warning for now since it's not fixed yet.

Comment: Didn't work! Tried adding it to the UI file as well as test file.

Answer (score 12):

Seem to be a known bug of current nativebase.io Release: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3109

Additional Info, what exactly the issue is about: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated#how-do-i-use-this-in-my-app

Answer (score 4):

use the following code to avoid the warning message of usenativedriver

```
  Animated.timing(new Animated.Value(0), 
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false //make it as false
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `Animated.spring` or any other Animation specify `useNativeDriver: true` of `useNativeDriver: false`.

Example:

```
Animated.spring(this.position, {
    toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    useNativeDriver: true,
}).start();
```

The `Animated.spring` is being called in `onPanResponderRelease` function.

Answer (score 2):

In react native SDK 39 you have to write following code:

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified.']);
```

Answer (score 1):

native-base fixed this as of January.  Get at least v2.15.2

`yarn add native-base@^2.15.2`

Release notes: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.15.2

Answer (score 0):

It will mostly be a matter of finding all instances of Animated.timing or Animated.spring and adding 
useNativeDriver: true to the config.

Answer (score 0):

Using class Component just add the `Animated.timing` inside `componentDidMount()` and define `useNativeDriver` as true or false

```
class App extends Component {

    animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.squareBG}/>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.square, {opacity: this.animatedValue}]}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this in my `App.js` and worked for me :)

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified.',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution if you are getting this type of warning in your terminal.
Warning: dynamic: `useNativeDriver` was not defined. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to 'true' or 'false'.

I tried to remove this warning with YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']) and then got this warning.

Warn:YellowBox has been replaced by LogBox. Please call LogBox.ignoreLogs() instead.

So I found this and it is working fine in my project.
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Driver: `useNativeDriver''])
add this line in index.js folder.

Answer (score -1):

****if you using useeffect put inside useeffect****

> *****working for me*****

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the issue flagged but instead a way to hide the warning and pretend it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -4):

just search animated.timing on folder ~\node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\ and add manually useNativeDriver: true or false

Comment: If you make changes like this you will most likely want to use the 'patch-package' module in order to generate a patch of the changes you made and automatically apply them if/when node_modules is reinstalled