# React Native Material - uncaught error while using FAB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I was just creating an Inbox page in React Native function and added react native material, when I just tried to use Floating Action Button from react native material for Add button, throws the below error.

`Error: Attempting to run JS driven animation on animated node that has been moved to "native" earlier by starting an animation with` useNativeDriver: true`, js engine: hermes`

I don't know how to resolve this error. I'm sure that the error comes only after adding FAB.

[Click here!](https://share.internxt.com/d/sh/file/c227205e230e0a5548a9/9e40fa55f61163404a5de52978c3bbfbd220d35b0b46c886a715d8ea971cfb0d) to see the screenshot of the error.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Component File:**

```
import { Avatar, Box, FAB, Icon, Stack, Text } from "@react-native-material/core";
import { useState } from "react";
import {  Modal } from "react-native";
import React from 'react';

const Inbox = ({ navigation }) => {



    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)

    const handlePress = () => {
        setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
    }

    return (

        <>
                <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType="slide">
                    <Text>Compose Mail</Text>
                    <Stack fill justify="start" items="center" mt={20}>
                        <FAB icon={props => <Icon name="close" {...props} />} color="primary" onPress={handlePress} />
                    </Stack>
                </Modal>
                

            <Stack fill justify="start" items="center" mt={20}>
                <FAB icon={props => <Icon name="plus" {...props} />} color="primary" onPress={handlePress} />
            </Stack>

        </>
    );
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a `useEffect` call in the FAB component which creates a non-native animation.
Changing animation to `useNativeDriver:true` solves the issue for me. [soruce](https://github.com/yamankatby/react-native-material/issues/53#issuecomment-1435639334)

Another way is update the dependency to latest version which will solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell me, Where do I need to change `useNativeDriver:true`?
And React Native material package is up to date...

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61117885/13632102)

Comment: Yes, I already saw that answer. I don't know where to the animation config to change useNativeDriver:true